# N gunmen in a field

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

Let *n* be an odd integer. In some field, *n* gunmen are placed such that all pairwise distances between them are different. At a signal, every gunman takes out his gun and shoots the closest gunman. Prove the following:
a) At least one gunman survives.
b) No gunman is shot more than 5 times.
c) The trajectory of the bullets does not intersect.

I solved part A with the extremal principle, however, I think it lacks rigour.(I  will be posting my solution shortly.) I would appreciate a rigorous one or an alternate solution.
I am clueless when it comes to part B.
Solved part C with some geometry, just thought that I should share it anyway.

EDITS:
Part C is solved with the theorem: In a triangle, sides opposite to larger angles are longer. Suppose A $\rightarrow$ C and B$\rightarrow$D and their trajectories intersect, this implies four inequalities with the sides and diagonals of $ABCD$. And with the above theorem we prove that the sum of the angles is $<360$. Contradiction.

EDIT 2: The best solutions seem to be from Maciek for Part B and Micah for part A. Since Maciek has enough upvotes and will stay at the top of the feed, I have "accepted" Micah's answer.

Comment: Btw. b) may not be true, if we allow uneven fields ;-)

Comment: Does this field have characteristic 0?

Comment: $n$ needs to be greater than $1$ or the only gunman has nobody to shoot

Comment: Part (c) should perhaps be restated as “The trajectories of the bullets do not intersect, unless they intersect at every point.”

Comment: @CiaPan, all the statements are still true in that case, so $n$ does not need to be greater than $1$.

Comment: It's a trick question, all gunmen shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: @Stefan Fortunately the examiners were not in a mood to torture high schoolers.

Comment: If we retain all other conditions except for the fact that shooters are in 3(or $n$ dimensional euclidean space), (a) will hold. What about (b) and (c)?

Comment: @talegari (b) does not and (c) does. Though I think a higher number, instead of 5, in (b) will make it true(depending on n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another version of a):

> By the pigeonhole principle, "someone doesn't get shot" is equivalent to "someone gets shot twice" whenever $n > 1$. Consider the two gunmen who are closest together. They will shoot each other. If anyone else shoots them, we're done; if not, remove them and induct.

More formally:

> We'll proceed by induction. If $n=1$, the [gunman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Harvey_Oswald) survives. Now, let $n>1$ be odd, and suppose that someone survives in every configuration involving $k<n$ gunmen with $k$. Take a configuration involving $n$ gunmen, and consider the two gunmen who are closest together. They will shoot each other. If anyone else shoots them, then one of them is being shot twice, and thus by the pigeonhole principle there must be some other gunman who isn't being shot at all. If nobody else shoots them, we can remove them from the field without affecting whom anybody else is shooting. This will give a configuration involving $n-2$ gunmen, which is an odd number; thus, by the induction hypothesis, at least one of those gunmen will survive. In either case, we have shown that there is a surviving gunman, so this completes the proof.

Comment: I used a similar version, but it seemed pretty hand-wavy. This looks better, but could you please elaborate on how to induct in this case?

Comment: Like this?${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 15):

Suppose that two gunmen $(A, B)$ shoot a special individual $C$.  Then if you consider the triangle $ABC$, the longest side is $|AB|$, so the $\angle ACB > 60^\circ$.  And you cannot put 6 people around somebody where all the angles are greater than $60^\circ$.

Answer (score 6):

a) All pairwise distances are different. --edit: this argument is insufficient --

> One gunman must be further away from any peers than any other, and his peers will shoot each other instead of him. If there were an even number, they could be placed in pairs, but if the number is odd and the pairwise distances are unique, this is not possible.

b) To be shot $k$ times, a gunman must be the closest member to $k$ others. Thus, what is the maximum packing density at which point no more gunmen can be added without drawing fire?

> The measure is circularly symmetric, so we need the maximum packing density of circles, which is hexagonal. However, in hexagonal packing the distances between the centres are all equal; if the distances are adjusted to be inequal, the sixth circle cannot pack more closely to the centre circle than to its neighbours (which would then draw their fire), leaving the maximum packing density around a centre at $5$.

c) Intersecting trajectories would require that distances $AC < BD$, and form a quadrilateral $ABCD$. But in a convex planar quadrilateral $ABCD$...

> points $B,D$ are always closer to $C$ than $C$ is to $A$. Only in a concave quadrilateral can $AB < CD$, in which $AC$ and $BD$ do not intersect.

Comment: Nice except I don't understand c), please spell it out. WLOG we pick AB<CD. But why must points [CD] be closer to B than B is to A?

Comment: I think for part (c) you actually want to show that at least one of $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, or $BD$ (you can't really know which in advance) is less than $CD$. It's easy to construct a convex quadrilateral with diagonals $AB$ and $CD$ such that $BC=BD=2$ but $AB=1$, so it's not literally true that "points $CD$ are always closer to $B$ than $B$ is to $A$." (By the way, I found it confusing that you wrote "quadrilateral $ABCD$" rather than "quadrilateral $ACBD$" when $AB$ was a diagonal rather than a side.)

Comment: I love your answer to part "a", that was genius, and I can understand it without any complex math. Simple proof by counter-example.

Comment: I don't think your a) quite works. It's certainly not true that the gunman who's farthest away from any other doesn't get shot -- perhaps you have two gunmen a thousand miles apart, a million miles away from all the rest who are within a mile of each other.

Comment: @Micah Exactly. I removed such pairs, if they exist, and this process continues till either the person along the longest distance does not get shot or in the end only one person remains.

Comment: What does "further away from any peers than any other" mean in (a)? Every gunman has $n-1$ distances to peers. Is the mentioned gunman one with the smallest sum, the smallest minimum, the smallest maximum, something else?

Comment: @Micah, JiK: You're right. I've added a warning for now until a) is fixed; I need to both redefine the measure and include cycle-elimination.

Comment: @DavidK: I've relabelled the diagonals to AC and BD. What I'm trying to elucidate is that given a quadrilateral ABCD, moving C to C' along the line AC, when C' is closer to A than to B or D, then B and D will be closer to C' than each other. I suspect the answers to all 3 parts can be better explained by first describing pairs and triangles, since all the geometries reduce to those.

Comment: @PhilH That's better but not quite right. Let $A=(0,0),B=(10^{-9},1),C'=(2,0),D=(10^{-9},-1).$ Then $C'$ is closer to $A$ than to $B$ or $D$, but $B$ and $D$ are closer to each other than to $C'$. (Of course $B$ and $D$ do not shoot each other in this example, but it's because of their proximity to $A$, not their proximity to $C'$.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

(a)

> Let each shooting be a directed edge. Then prove that any cycle must be a 2-cycle. Then prove that removing all cycles results in a nonzero number of paths.

(b)

> *Maciek* gave a more or less full answer already so there is no hint left to give.

(c)

> It is indeed a geometric fact.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, my understanding of graph theory is basic. I had tried on similar lines, but that seemed to be less rigorous.